# glkView drawInRect not called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am learning OpenGLES and I am trying to put a GLKViewer inside an UIViewController.

I know I can come around the main issues by using GLViewController, but I am trying to learn how to do it this way.

I found this question, [Nesting GLKView into UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755288/nesting-glkview-into-uiviewcontroller) and [Nested GLKView and GLKViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244525/nested-glkview-and-glkviewcontroller) but I must be missing something even though I think I am doing all the right steps because when I run my project, I am not getting to the drawInRect print line.

In the storyboard I am pointing the ViewController as the delegate of the glkview component.

I tried to keep the code as simple as possible and any help will be apreciated:

***MyController.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface MyGLController : UIViewController <GLKViewDelegate>
{
    GLuint vertexBufferID;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GLKView *glview;

@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKBaseEffect *baseEffect;

@end
```

***MyGLController.m***

```
#import "MyGLController.h"

@implementation MyGLController

//@synthesize baseEffect;

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.glview.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:
     kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

     [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.glview.context];
    printf("View Loaded");
}


- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    printf("DrawInRect");
}

@end
```

*** Update ***

As far as I can tell the glkview is hooked up properly as suggested per and added the  josh-knapp and called setNeedsDisplay.

In case there's something I am missing, I have uploaded a copy of the project here: https://github.com/jcrogel/OpenGLDebug.git

I am a total noob in this so I apologize for any silly oversight :)

Comment: Ok I have noticed that I have gotten a 'close' vote and 2 down votes without further explanation of what is wrong in the question or how my question would have been better. Any feedback to regain my points would be appreciated.

Comment: I think downvoters should explain their reason instead of blindly marking this for close. The OP obviously made an effort here to provide both an explanation and code. A simple comment requesting missing info would have helped.

Comment: For me, I didn't initialize with a context and that's why it wasn't called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't say you hooked up the glview property of MyGLController in the storyboard, so verify that.

Next, you're setting up the glview context after it loads.  Without a GLKViewController, there is nothing telling the glview it needs to be drawn.  Make sure you call `[self.glview setNeedsDisplay]` somewhere after the context is set up.

Comment: Thanks I gave that a try but it didn't work, I have updated the question with the extra info and a link to the github repo that I added with the project itself

Comment: Just to clarify, the call I needed to do was:
    self.glview.setNeedsDisplay = YES;

Comment: That should be: self.glview.enableSetNeedsDisplay = YES;

Comment: I had to do both : 

self.glview.enableSetNeedsDisplay = YES;
[self.glview setNeedsDisplay];

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem.

By default, xcode sets the `enable setNeedsDisplay` checkbox to `NO` in `GLKView` property list.
Once I changed it, it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me. I had the same issue. Checking the box fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see this question was already answered.  But I had the same problem, with a different solution.  I figured I'd post the info here on the off chance others might be able to benefit from it.

**Problem Description**

While using GLKView and GLKViewController, the render loop function (drawInRect) is called once, but not called again.

**Possible Cause**

Some methods to CViewController have been implemented incorrectly, without calling their supers.  The following code illustrates three such functions.  The examples below have the three functions implemented correctly, calling their supers.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
}
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
}
```